# How can find row of min value except row have special word in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I try to find row of min value in range exept row has special word.
For EX:

[image]

Now, I would like to find row of fruits which has min number exept "Watermelon".
And result should be is 5 (row of banana)

My idea is find second lowest value with

```
SecLowVal = objExcel.WorksheetFunction.Small(Range("B2:B6"),2)
```

and then we will find row of this value

```
For Each rngCell In Range("B2:B6")
    If rngCell.Value = SecLowVal Then
        Row = rngCell.Row
        Exit For
    End If
Next rngCell
msg(Row)
```

But in case:

[image]

It will be wrong, I don't know is there any function or the way to do like that find row of min value except row has special word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula.

```
=CELL("row",INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(MIN(IF(A2:A6<>"Watermelon",B2:B6,"")),B2:B6,0)))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

***Edited update formula based on your comment.***

```
=CELL("row",INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(MIN(IF(A2:A6<>"Watermelon",B2:B6,"")),IF(A2:A6<>"Watermelon",B2:B6,""),0)))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

===========================  VBA Function ============================

```
    Public Function MinBasedOnCondition(InRange As Range, valRange As Range, ConditionItem As String) As Variant
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Dim ValueArray()
    Dim MyArray()
    Dim CelCount, inc, MinVal, i As Long
    Dim Condition As String
    Dim ArrItems, Result

    Condition = ConditionItem
        CelCount = Application.CountIf(InRange, "<>" & Condition)
    ReDim ValueArray(CelCount)

    inc = 1

    For Each MyCell In InRange
        If MyCell.Value <> Condition Then
            ValueArray(inc) = MyCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            inc = inc + 1
        End If
    Next

    ArrItems = ""
    For i = 1 To CelCount
        ArrItems = ArrItems & ValueArray(i) & ", "
    Next

    ArrItems = Left(ArrItems, Len(ArrItems) - 2)

    MyArray = Array(ArrItems)
    MinVal = Evaluate("Min(" & Join(MyArray, ",") & ")")

    For Each MyCell In valRange
        If MyCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> Condition Then
            If MyCell.Value = MinVal Then
                Result = MyCell.Row
                    Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MinBasedOnCondition = Result
End Function
```

***Use in worksheet***

[image]

Comment: Only issue with this solution is when "Watermelon" shares a minimum value with another Fruit on a row beneath. In this instance the result of the formula will be the "Watermelon" row.

Comment: Then use this array formula `=CELL("row",INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(MIN(IF(A2:A6<>"Watermelon",B2:B6,"")),IF(A2:A6<>"Watermelon",B2:B6,""),0)))`   Please check edited answer and accept if it works for you.

Comment: Cool that works, thanks. OP wasn't mine, just a curious observer.

Comment: Glad to know it works for you. Accept the answer. Tick it as green.

Comment: OP = original post. On this website you cannot accept answers unless you were the author of the post. I was not the author, stop bloody asking me to accept the answer.

Comment: @MJV Oh! I do not notice, you are not questioner. No issue -- enjoy the formula.

Comment: Hello harun, I am trying to convert your formula to VBA code.

Comment: Could you please change this formula to vba code. I tried but it alway say error

Comment: @Bruce Ok. Let me try to do it by VBA.

Comment: @Bruce See the updated post. Let me know if you are not able to use the function.

Comment: Yes, I got it. But it's seem to be quite a long. Whatever Thank you so much for attempt to help. I will vote for you

Answer (score 2):

With `Range` [AutoFilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) and `WorksheetFunction` [Min()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841245.aspx) methods, code gest shorter, with neither loops nor variables to be declared:

```
Function FindMinFilterWaterMelon() As Long
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*Watermelon" ' show all values in range, except "Watermelon"
        With .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| reference column "B" filtered cells
            FindMinFilterWaterMelon = .Find(WorksheetFunction.Min(.Cells), , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext).row '<--| get row of cell with minimum value
        End With
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```

a possible enhancement of which could be passing it fruit to discard:

```
Function FindMinFilterWaterMelon(fruitToDiscard As String) As Long
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*" & fruitToDiscard ' show all values in range, except passed fruit to discard
        With .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| reference column "B" filtered cells
            FindMinFilterWaterMelon = .Find(WorksheetFunction.Min(.Cells), , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext).row '<--| get row of cell with minimum value
        End With
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: you can just do anything with `AutoFilter` , what about baking a cake :)

Comment: @ShaiRado, well current use of Excel is almost always a matter of querying a database (although _real_ databases should be handled with different tools), i.e. filtering it., then... But I saw you started using it, too!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to approach it in a different way. First I would filter out the "**Watermelon**" row.

Then loop through the Range containing only visible cells (using the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))`), and finding the Minimum Value.

**Code**

```
Sub FindMinFilterWaterMelon()

Dim LastRow As Long, RowFound As Long
Dim MinVal, Rng As Range, cell As Range

Range("A1:B1").AutoFilter
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

' show all values in range, except "Watermelon"
With Range("A1:B" & LastRow)
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*Watermelon*"
End With

' set range only to visible cells
Set Rng = Range("B2:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

MinVal = 100000 ' init value of MinVal
' loop through all cells in Range visible cells and look for minimum value
For Each cell In Rng.Cells
    If cell.Value < MinVal Then
        MinVal = cell.Value
        RowFound = cell.Row
    End If
Next cell

MsgBox "Min value of " & MinVal & " was found at row " & RowFound

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Rado, I checked it, That's a great idea but with you match function, when I check it always returns row 2, I think with picture 2 it should return row 4. And how can I turn off filter and back to initial state

Comment: @Rado In case Orange 5, Watermelon 3, Lemon 3, Banana 3, Apple 3 (Like a picture number 2). It will return min value is 3 and row 3. I think it should row 4

Comment: @Bruce try edited code, I modifd the direction of the second half, how to find the Minimum value and store the location of that cell (row)

Comment: Yes, it's run exactly what I want. Sorry because I just can vote for 1 person. However, I really really thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Bruce  it's ok, you should vote as answer the solution you think its best for u